Changing hx-replace-url with value from form
I have a form that receives user input.  I need to use that input to dynamically change an associated hx-replace-url.  Here is the snippet of html
  <div>
    <p>Create any item</p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <span>with uri:</span>
      <input id="prefix" name="prefix">
      <input value="2653ccd5-f76c-45e9-906a-468c9accdfc7" id="new_subject" style="width: 50rem;" name="new_subject">
      <div>
        <button hx-post="/item" hx-target="#card_container" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-replace-url="/item/<<MY VALUES FROM THE FORM>>">Create Item</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

Is there any way that I can customise this hx-replace-url form values just enetered into the form?

I found an answer here htmx, push url with form value. that works.
In summary, I set hx-replace-url="true"
As an aside, I am also redirecting soon after that.  So this combination works.  I haven't tested hx-replace-url="ture" without the redirect.
